# Linked forms won't update data in table

Tags: ms-access

I made linked forms to input data into a table called t_Transactions. These forms contain data from 3 tables. Those tables are:

- t_Group: consists of group number (primary key) and group name
- t_Member: consists of group number (foreign key), member number (primary key) and member name
- t_Transactions: consists of transaction number (primary key), group number (foreign key), member number (foreign key), debit transaction, and credit transaction.

The first form (let's call it form A) contains data from the t_Group table. A second form (let's call it form B) is linked to Form A, and it contains data from the t_Member table, and a subform containing data from t_transaction. The subform only has 3 fields: transaction number, debit transaction, and credit transaction. (See picture 1 [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8knP.jpg) and [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMwLO.jpg) for form pictures)

Now when I input the "transaction number", "debit transaction" and "credit transaction" fields in the t_transaction subform in Form B, all of the fields in the t_transaction table are automatically filled, but the group number field is left blank, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciGwL.jpg). I want the group number field to be filled with data corresponding to Form A. How can I do this? I checked all my [relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOs6q.jpg), and it is correct.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try and add your GroupNumber as a field to your Form B, just display it and see if the number is correct etc from the parent form. It might not get transferred right, or if it is you can simply hide the field form later.

Comment: Can a member ever change to another group? If not, no reason to save group number in t_Transactions. The group can be retrieved through t_Member.

Comment: Hi @June7, yes the members can change to other groups.

Comment: @Xander, the number is correct from the parent form

Comment: Saving the group number into t_Transactions will require code (macro or VBA). The real trick is figuring out what event to put code into. Is it really necessary to save the group number in the transaction record?

Comment: Yes it is necessary to save the group number @June7

Comment: Code is fairly simple, behind the subform: `Me!GroupNum = Parent!GroupNum`. Now figure out which event of subform to put code in. Maybe transaction number control AfterUpdate.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! @June7